# How to set ttl manually with Redis::set method?

Tags: laravel, redis

In laravel 9 app I write redis(5.0.7) value with Redis::set method, but in this case it has

```
TTL = does not expire
```

I try to set ttl manually, like

```
Redis::set('key', $value, now()->addHours($data_caching_hours));
```

I got error:

```
ERR syntax error
```

My quess was wrong and I did not find if Redis::set can set ttl value?
I prefer to set ttl value manually for any object, as ttl can be different for any object.

In config/cache.php I have :

```
    'redis' => [
        'driver' => 'redis',
        'connection' => 'cache',
        'lock_connection' => 'default',
    ],
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Valid decision is :

```
Redis::set('key', ($to_serialize ? serialize($val) : $val) );
Redis::expire($'key', $caching_hours * 3600);
```